# Polyglot Language Selector 2 - using the id's

Tags: jquery

I'm using Polyglot Language Selector 2 and its working well - however, I have a question:

It utilises the following: `data-lang-id="en_US"`

Is it possible to use that within jQuery as a specific ID? If so, how would I achieve that, for example:

```
if($("#data-lang-id").val("English")){
        //alert("English");

    }
```

The above doesn't work and I am not surprised as it's not unique to `"en_US"`.

Any advice, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if ( $('div[data-lang-id="English"]').length ) {
  alert('English!');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rkxxc5cu/